# frame id keeps changing, imacros script not working

Tags: javascript, imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 1
TAB T=1
wait seconds = 6
CLICK X=16 Y=99
FRAME F=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=3
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=4
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=5
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=6
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=7
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=8
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=9
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
FRAME F=10
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
```

The frame id keeps changing, sometimes it even goes as high as 74.

I tried the java code to find out the frame id, but being a rookie, i was not able to implement that in my code.

Can anyone create a js file for me with the loop for frame id finder, and the rest of my imacros?

Thanks

Comment: Show us you have at least tried ! Asking "can you do this for me" will not result in an answer to your question.

Comment: I can make js file... why?

Comment: Tried this one - https://jsfiddle.net/cdfwq7t6/ @G.Hamaide

Comment: @macroscripts please help http://prntscr.com/a9sdns
want macros to click on the first url of this window. frame id keeps changing and it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the prior commands:

```
iimPlayCode(
    "TAB T=1" + "\n" +
    "WAIT SECONDS=6" + "\n" +
    "CLICK X=16 Y=99" + "\n"
);
```

To find the frame and click the first link in it, you may try something like this:

```
for (i = 1; ; i++) {
    var ret = iimPlayCode(
        "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n" +
        "FRAME F=" + i + "\n" +
        'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0' + "\n"
    );
    if (ret == 1)
        break;
}
```

Comment: It isnt clicking on the window. check screenshot to get a good idea. http://prntscr.com/a9sdns

Comment: In order to get the best idea, you should rather provide a link for this window.

Comment: http://www.leadsleap.com/clickview.php?q=55a&s=m&d=8048&i=ftwseounli9&a=wealth4u2&l=aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy5sZWFkc2xlYXAuY29tJTJGbWVtYmVycyUyRmluZGV4LnBocA==

Comment: 'FRAME F={{!EXTRACT}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#ctr1>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0'

The imacros doesnt moves through these 2 lines. it isnt clicking

Comment: An iim-macro really doesn't allow solving this issue, try the update that includes a js-script.

Comment: The script seems working as it is finding out the frame number continously. But, the first command of the imacros, clicking a button to open up the window, it isnt in the js script. can you add that?